# Sorting collection and sub-collection at the same time

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, iqueryable

I have an `IQueryable<Product>` that needs to be sorted by `Name`. Each `Product` has an `IQueryable<Category>` that also needs to be sorted by `Name`. I'm having a hard time expressing this in Linq. I could loop through the products and sort each category list, but it seems messy. Hoping a Linq ninja has a smarter solution.

My `Product` class looks like:

```
public class Product {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IQueryable<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

My `Category` class looks like:

```
public class Category { 
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Currently, I'm doing this:

```
 var myProducts = products.OrderBy(x => x.Name).Select(x => new Product { 
    Name = x.Name,
    Categories = x.Categories(y => y.Name)
});
```

The trouble is, when using something like NHibernate, this creates new Product objects, essentially disconnecting the product from the NH session.

Comment: I don't think that's messy.  Sorting the products and sorting the categories are two totally conceptually different operations; it isn't wrong to have them separated in code.

Comment: What is the end state you're trying to achieve?  A List<Category>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to modify the `Product` object in any way that could affect persistence and you don't want to create new `Product` instances.

So add this to `Product` class:

```
public IOrderedEnumerable<Category> CategoriesOrderedByName
{
  get { return this.Categories.OrderBy(y => y.Name); }
}
```

And use `product.CategoriesOrderedByName` instead when you need the sorted version in your UI code.

Without this anyone using your class has no expectation that the `Category` objects are sorted in any way.  With this you are being explicit in informing consumers of your class what to expect and that you intend to always return them in a sorted order.  You can also use `IOrderedEnumerable<>` as the return type to make allow further sub-sorting using `ThenBy()`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you want? You do not get a list of products that each has a list of categories, however. That's impossible using LINQ because you can not alter a collection using LINQ, you can only make a new collection from an existing one (in my example `p.Categories` is the existing collection, `SortedCategories` the new one).

```
from p in products
orderby p.Name
select new
{
    Product = p,
    SortedCategories = from c in p.Categories
                       orderby c.Name
                       select c
}
```

You say you have `IQueryable`'s. Does that mean that you are querying against a database using this LINQ statement? I'm not sure how well this transforms to SQL (performance-wise).

Answer (score 0):

Why not just sort the enumerable in place?

```
products = products.OrderBy(x => x.Name);
products.ToList().ForEach(x => x.Categories = x.Categories.OrderBy(y => y.Name));
```

As others have stated, this may perform poorly if you're connected.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enumerate over the `Product` objects in sorted order and within each `Product` you want the `Categories` in sorted order, you could do something like this.

```
var sorted = products
    .Select(
        p => new
        {
            Product = p,
            Categories = p.Categories.OrderBy(c => c.Name)
        }
    )
    .OrderBy(x => x.Product.Name);
```

It looks like this is basically what [Ronald](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611568/sorting-collection-and-sub-collection-at-the-same-time/3611628#3611628) has, only without using LINQ syntax.